# How to compress multiple lists into one list and keeping the same size list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, merge

I am trying to merge multiple lists that outputs 1 list of all the values and keep the zeros.
The indices and values need to be kept in the same index location.

Input:

```
list1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0]
list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12]
list3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list5 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list6 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list8 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list9 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list10 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list11 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list12 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is what I want the output to be..

Output:

```
results = [1,0,0,4,5,6,7,0,0,0,11,12]
```

Comment: Loop through the lists, summing all the elements into the result list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with list comprehension and all lists have the same lengths..

```
results = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    results.append(list1[i]+list2[i]+list3[i]+list4[i]+list5[i]+list6[i]+list7[i]+list8[i]+list9[i]+list10[i]+list11[i]+list12[i])
```

This would get the job done even though it's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over all the lists in parallel and sum the corresponding elements.

```
results = list(map(sum, zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9, list10, list11, list12)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd

data = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, 
        list7, list8, list9, list10,list11, list12]

sum_l = pd.DataFrame(data).sum().tolist()

# [1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 11, 12]
```

Comment: I like the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

```py
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, ...]

[sum(lst) for lst in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```

**edit** same as @Barmar's answer, fundamentally -- I didn't see his answer at posting

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [*map(sum, zip(*[(eval(f'list{i}')) for i in range(1, 13)]))]
```